# How to Package Tomcat Setup with MSIX/InstallShield for On-Prem Deployment?

Tags: installshield, msix

I'm currently exploring deployment strategies for our Java-based web application that runs on Tomcat in Windows OS environments. My goal is to create a seamless Tomcat setup package (which includes a WAR file) and deliver it as a Windows installable package.

Questions:

Q-1: I came across this Tomcat installer: https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.80/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.80.exe. How was this installer developed? Is there any documentation or source that can provide insights into its creation?

Q-2: Is the MSIX Packaging Tool sufficient to develop such a package, or would I benefit from using InstallShield for this purpose?

Comment: Why do you want Apache to be included inside an MSIX? Do you need to run multiple versions of Apache on those machines?

Comment: We aim to bundle Apache with the MSIX package to streamline the installation process at the customer's site. By doing so, our support team can ensure a consistent environment and mitigate potential compatibility issues. Additionally, this approach simplifies deployment, eliminating the need for our customers to install Apache separately before deploying the WAR.